# Setting variables using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

having a bash at using Tkinter - What I am trying to make is a small GUI which runs a system call function.

I want to be able to set v1, v2, v3 as string items using the GUI - they are for use in the "command" function.

```
def system_call( step_name, cmd ):
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as scall:
        print "Script failed at %s stage - exit code was %s" % (step_name, scall.returncode)
        exit()


def command(v1, v2, v3):
    # Commandline string
    return v1 + " " + v2 + " " + v3
```

Below you will find the interface set up.

```
# Create and name the window
        root = Tk()
        root.title("GUI - TEST VERSION")

        # Set the variables needed for function

        v1 = StringVar()
        v2 = StringVar()
        v3 = StringVar()

        # Make text entry box
        w = Label(root, text="V1")
        w.pack()
        text_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = v1.get())
        text_entry.pack()

        w = Label(root, text="V2")
        w.pack()
        text_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = v2.get())
        text_entry.pack()

        w = Label(root, text="V3")
        w.pack()
        text_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = v3.get())
        text_entry.pack()

        # Add a 'Run' button 
        b = Button(root, text="Run fuction", command= system_call(Command call, command(v1, v2,v3)))
        b.pack()

        # Call the GUI
        root.mainloop()
```

Getting an error which states that string objects and instance objects cannot be catted.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why are you calling `get`, rather than assigning the `StringVar` objects themselves to `textvariable`?

Comment: `command= system_call(command(v1, v2,v3))` This will _call_ `system_call`, _not_ bind the function as a callback to the button.

Comment: I want to call the system call! - im getting an error saying that string and instance objects cannot be catted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using your variables in the wrong way.

Here, you want to use the variable itself, not the content:

```
text_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=v1) # remove .get(), same for the other lines
```

And here, you want to use the content, not the variable:

```
def command(v1, v2, v3):
    return v1.get() + " " + v2.get() + " " + v3.get() # add .get()
```

Also, when you bind your `system_call` function to the button, you are *calling* the function and binding the result to `command`. Instead, use a lambda:

```
b = Button(root, text="Run fuction", command=lambda: system_call('Command call', command(v1, v2,v3)))
```

Comment: Thank you! First go at this so got a little confused!

Comment: I recommend against using lambda in this case. Lambdas are difficult for many people to understand, and really should only be used when there's no better option. It's better to create a command specifically for the button, it will make the program much easier to maintain over time.